# Pulling in matrix fields from a Single onto a different page

Tags: matrix

Just wondering how to pull content from a matrix field on my homepage into another .html file. Basically taking the content from a single and placing it into a different template. This is what I have so far:

```
{% for event in entry.homepage %}
    {% for block in entry.aloneImages %}
        {% for asset in block.image %}
              <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}"> <br />
        {% endfor %}
        {{ block.source }}
        {{ block.credit }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to define `entry`, which can be done with [craft.entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) the same way you’d fetch any other entry(s).

```twig
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('homepage').first() %}

{% for block in entry.aloneImages %}
    {# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```